# Three recipes for one package Yocto/Openembedded

Tags: python-2.7, pjsip, yocto, openembedded

Is it possible in yocto to have a recipe in which I download a package (in this case PJSIP) and compile it. And in another recipe install the package, and in a third recipe compile and install the python lib of this package?
If yes, how can I do such a thing?
Thank you !

Comment: No. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's a suggestion I read in a forum.. But it seems to be useless. I want to do it because I cant get my python lib of this package installed...

Comment: Doing it on the separate recipes isn't supported at all. It'll be a lot easier to write a single, complete recipe. It's better that you close this question, and open a new one with your exact problem.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help !